# Twilio paging in phone number API - nodejs

Tags: node.js, pagination, twilio

I'm using the Twilio client, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers#local-instance) in node. I want to use pagination and also get total number of records(phone numbers) for a particular endpoint. I could not find any documentation related to it.
This is the code I have used.

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

// Find and then purchase a phone number
client
  .availablePhoneNumbers('US')
  .local.list({
    areaCode: '510',
  })
  .then(data => {
    const number = data[0];
    return client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({
      phoneNumber: number.phoneNumber,
    });
  })
  .then(purchasedNumber => console.log(purchasedNumber.sid));
```

Edit: I found out there is a way to pass pageNumber, pageSize.
`list({ pageNumber: 1 , pageSize: 10})`
but the results retrieved are not the same. If I execute the above, two times different sets of results are retrieved.
There is a `availablePhoneNumbers('US').local.page({ pageNumber: 1 , pageSize: 10})` as well that also gives some random results.

Comment: You should ask Twilio, if they don't offer this info by API, maybe they don't want you to have this. Anyway, I don't know what do you mean by "pagination", but try to check `data.length`

Comment: pagination: eg: skip 10 records and get next 10 which is the second page. Twilio has asked to ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [available phone numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers) does not have pagination and returns a random result set each time you request it. You can narrow down your search by [filtering on the list](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers#local-get-basic-filters) for things like country code or whether it contains certain number patterns, but you can't enumerate the entire library of Twilio numbers.

Comment: Thanks, there was no documentation on this